# Is there a way to pass a `constexpr` value into lambda so that it remains `constexpr` inside that lambda?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, template-meta-programming, constexpr

Here's what I want to do; posting the whole code because it's not too long and also to demonstrate the specific task I'm trying to solve. Basically, I need a way to iterate values from parameter pack by index (the index part is important, even though it's not required in this example).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <int First, int Last, typename Functor>
constexpr void static_for(Functor&& f)
{
    if constexpr (First < Last)
    {
        f(std::integral_constant<int, First>{});
        static_for<First + 1, Last, Functor>(std::forward<Functor>(f));
    }
}

template <size_t index, typename... Args>
auto value_by_index(Args&&... args) noexcept {
    return std::get<index>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}

template <typename... ValueTypes>
void traverse(ValueTypes... values)
{
    static_for<0, sizeof...(ValueTypes)>([&](int i) {
        auto v = value_by_index<static_cast<size_t>(i), ValueTypes...>(values...);
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    });
}

int main()
{
    traverse(0.0f, 1, 3.33, "str");

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error, of course, is:

```
<source>:24:71: error: 'i' is not a constant expression
```

If lambdas could have explicit template arguments, `i` would be such an argument and it would be obvious to the compiler that it's known at compile time. But that's not how lambdas work.

If you want to treat it as an X-Y problem, I suppose I don't specifically need to call a lambda inside my `static_for`, but I do need to call some piece of code that can access parameter pack(s) of `traverse` by index, and if `traverse` was a member function, I need to have access to its `this`.

Try it online: https://godbolt.org/z/eW4rnm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a generic lambda and a constexpr conversion operator [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

```
template <typename... ValueTypes>
void traverse(ValueTypes... values)
{
    static_for<0, sizeof...(ValueTypes)>([&](auto I)
    //                                       ~~~^
    {
        auto v = value_by_index<I>(values...);
        //                     ~^~
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    });
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dawcx9tmsP5kdFbK)

Use a template parameter list for the lambda expression [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
template <typename... ValueTypes>
void traverse(ValueTypes... values)
{
    static_for<0, sizeof...(ValueTypes)>([&]<int I>(std::integral_constant<int, I>)
    //                                       ~~~~^                             ~^~
    {
        auto v = value_by_index<I>(values...);
        //                     ~^~
        std::cout << v << std::endl;
    });
}
```

[**DEMO 2**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/0Cz1bhiZ7d7du9Gl)

Comment: Wow, such a silly mistake on my part! It seems that the type of `i` was `integral_constant`, not `int`?

Comment: @VioletGiraffe yes, and the type itself is known at compile-time. see that I'm not using the value of `i`

Comment: Since `std::integral_constant<int, I>` is convertible to `int`, and the conversion function is `constexpr`, it should be possible to use `i` in place of `decltype(i)::value`.

Comment: Well [compilers accept `value_by_index<i>(values...)`](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vxaHxxIjGFH7rU4F), and that makes sense since the conversion function does not need to read the value of `i`.

Comment: At first I didn't understand, but now I see what you did there. You've converted the value (`int`) into a template type holding that value as a non-type template parameter. `std::integral_constant` conveniently provides such a wrapper for integer types; a custom holder template could be written for values of other kinds. A lambda doesn't see its value argument as `constexpr`, but it does see the specific type it's invoked with, and there's `constexpr` conversion from the type to the value it holds. Clever.

Answer (score 4):

It's too late to play?

> Basically, I need a way to iterate values from parameter pack by index (the index part is important, even though it's not required in this example).

Sorry but... what about the good old use of `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` ?

Maintaining your `value_by_index()`, I propose the following C++14 solution based on `traverse()` with `traverse_helper()`

```
template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is, typename ... VTs>
void traverse_helper (F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>, VTs ... vs)
 { 
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (f(value_by_index<Is>(vs...)), 0)... };
 }

template <typename F, typename ... VTs>
void traverse (F f, VTs ... vs)
 { traverse_helper(f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(VTs)>{}, vs...); }
```

Observe that I've passed also the callable as parameter.

If you can use C++17 (as you tagged), `traverse_helper()` simply become

```
template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is, typename ... VTs>
void traverse_helper (F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>, VTs ... vs)
 { (f(value_by_index<Is>(vs...)), ...); }
```

You can call `traverse()` as follows

```
traverse([](auto x){ std::cout << x << std::endl; },
         0.0f, 1, 3.33, "str");
```

The following is a full C++14 compiling example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t I, typename ... As>
auto value_by_index (As && ... as) noexcept
 { return std::get<I>(std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<As>(as)...)); }

template <typename F, std::size_t ... Is, typename ... VTs>
void traverse_helper (F f, std::index_sequence<Is...>, VTs ... vs)
 { 
   using unused = int[];

   (void)unused { 0, (f(value_by_index<Is>(vs...)), 0)... };
 }

template <typename F, typename ... VTs>
void traverse (F f, VTs ... vs)
 { traverse_helper(f, std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(VTs)>{}, vs...); }

int main ()
 {
    traverse([](auto x){ std::cout << x << std::endl; },
             0.0f, 1, 3.33, "str");
 }
```

Comment: Interesting! I have to admit, I don't understand what `index_sequence` does and what it's for. Going to read on it.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe - `std::index_sequence`, and `std::make_index_sequence` that permit to generate sequences, are a very useful tool to works with variadic templates.